# How to create a SortedList<Tkey, TValue> with AutoFixture

Tags: c#, unit-testing, autofixture

I tried creating a `SortedList<,>` with AutoFixture, but it creates an empty list:

```
var list = fixture.Create<SortedList<int, string>>();
```

I've come up with the following which generates items, but is a little clunky:

```
fixture.Register<SortedList<int, string>>(
  () => new SortedList<int, string>(
    fixture.CreateMany<KeyValuePair<int,string>>().ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => x.Value)));
```

It is not generic (strongly typed to `int` and `string`).  I have two different `TValue` `SortedLists` to create.

**Any better suggestions?**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This looks like a feature AutoFixture ought to have out of the box, so I've added [an issue for that](https://github.com/AutoFixture/AutoFixture/issues/622).

Until then, though, you can do something like the following.

First, create an `ISpecimenBuilder`:

```
public class SortedListRelay : ISpecimenBuilder
{
    public object Create(object request, ISpecimenContext context)
    {
        var t = request as Type;
        if (t == null ||
            !t.IsGenericType ||
            t.GetGenericTypeDefinition() != typeof(SortedList<,>))
            return new NoSpecimen();

        var dictionaryType = typeof(IDictionary<,>)
            .MakeGenericType(t.GetGenericArguments());
        var dict = context.Resolve(dictionaryType);
        return t
            .GetConstructor(new[] { dictionaryType })
            .Invoke(new[] { dict });
    }
}
```

This implementation is only a proof of concept. It lacks proper error handling in various places, but it should demonstrate the approach. It resolves an `IDictionary<TKey, TValue>` from the `context`, and uses the returned value (which is filled) to create an instance of `SortedList<TKey, TValue>`.

In order to use it, you'll need to tell AutoFixture about it:

```
var fixture = new Fixture();
fixture.Customizations.Add(new SortedListRelay());

var actual = fixture.Create<SortedList<int, string>>();

Assert.NotEmpty(actual);
```

This test passes.